# Run Import-AzApiManagementApi in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

I am trying to set up the pipeline setup in Azure DevOps to import functions to API.
We have self hosted agent for Windows and we are using that as an agent.
We are trying to run the below command

[image]

I have tried installing the below before running the import command:
[image]

When we run it in Azure CLI( not in pipeline) we are able to execute it without a problem.
I have tried running the same command in Powershell tasks ,Azure CLI, Azure Powershell inline scripts and so on ( all the available options in DevOps pipeline I have tried) .
I am getting something or the other error and not able to proceed.
Few errors I have seen is as below:

[image]

[image]

Is there a definite task available in azure pipeline to run this module?

Comment: Post your actual pipeline YAML.

Comment: Its not YAML, we are using classic pipeline. I have used different tasks in Powershell (including task version 5) , Azure CLi etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install the Az Module and AzureRM module in your self-hosted agent first. Then run the pipeline to check if it works.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber
```

In Microsoft-hosted agents, these modules are pre-installed.
For more information, you could refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops#error-could-not-find-the-modules-module-name-with-version-version-if-the-module-was-recently-installed-retry-after-restarting-the-azure-pipelines-task-agent).

Comment: which task I have to choose? is it Azure CLI? or any of those powershell tasks?

Comment: Please install the modules in your self-hosted agent without using azure pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-8.1.0